# Handle back button in scrollableView

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

My app is all enclosed inside a `ScrollView`. When the user clicks the `Android` *back* button, I'd like to go back to the previews page of the scrollable view, instead of closing the app. The app should close only when the user clicks the back button while on page 0. Is this possible, and how?

Comment: Do you maintain a position variable which allows the system to know what page you're currently viewing?

Comment: Yes, I do that so that I know the navigation history, but actually you don't need it just to track the position: You can just use scrollableView.currentPage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: Use the android:back event AND set the main window as "modal: true"

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
  modal: true,
  exitOnClose:true
});

win.addEventListener('android:back', function (e) {
  // do what you want here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@danmaz74 Your code didn't work for me as expected, instead this worked OK

```
var secondWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
  modal: true
});
secondWindow.addEventListener('android:back', function (e) {
   secondWindow.close();
});
```

And since you want the app to exit on the first window.

```
var firstWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
     exitOnClose : true
});
```